# Uniquely sorting a list of lists in Python

Tags: python, list, sorting, large-data

I have a list of lists -

```
super_list = [seconds, self.flowdata, key]
```

where seconds is a ten digit number, self. flowdata is a list of 160 integers and key is an identifying string.  Printing super_list would yield many iterations of the following structure, all with different values,

example:

```
"[[1509321600], 
  ['1', '-1', '4', '7', '7', '1', '-8', '-14', '-24', '-29', '-25', '-24', '-9', '-4', '0', '0', '-5', '-10', '-6', '-5', '7', '-4', '-4', '-11', '5', '3', '9', '5', '3', '3', '6', '-6', '-8', '-6', '-6', '25', '23', '30', '22', '13', '-7', '0', '-1', '-18', '-24', '-28', '-24', '-24', '-18', '-14', '-14', '-12', '-13', '-11', '-15', '-16', '-8', '-3', '-4', '-2', '11', '29', '38', '40', '41', '29', '34', '25', '20', '15', '31', '22', '16', '2', '8', '21', '39', '43', '45', '38', '39', '37', '38', '41', '43', '42', '38', '34', '34', '25', '25', '29', '18', '23', '27', '26', '18', '15', '15', '11', '17', '10', '11', '4', '-3', '-12', '-17', '-14', '6', '5', '13', '4', '-21', '-22', '-16', '-12', '-6', '4', '16', '9', '17', '16', '16', '16', '15', '12', '12', '7', '-2', '-12', '-13', '-5', '-7', '-8', '-12', '-15', '-14', '-11', '-8', '-1', '-1', '-3', '-12', '-7', '-6', '-7', '5', '4', '2', '3', '1', '0', '-12', '-12', '-13', '-17', '-18', '-18', '-15', '-13', '-13', '-16', '-17', '-18', '-18', '-19', '-16', '-13'], 
  '1441-4731-1-10/30/2017']
```

Each set (or row if you like, as seen above) of seconds, flowdata and key are related.

I want to sort super_list so that seconds is ordered from smallest to largest, but also with its correlating flowdata and key in the same numerical 'row' in super_list.

i.e. say the above example was to be the first in the sorted list(1509321600 was the smallest number of seconds in the seconds list), the above flowdata would also be the first in flowdata and the above key "1441-4731-1-10/30/2017" would be the first key.

Help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming your list looks like: `[[seconds1, flowdata1, key1], [seconds2, flowdata2, key2], ...]`:

Just use `super_list.sort()`.

This will sort by the fields in lexicographic (left-to-right) order. Since `seconds` is the leftmost field, all entries will be sorted by it.

You can also sort by a specific field by using the `key` parameter to `sort`, e.g.:

```
super_list.sort(key=lambda row: row[0]) #sort by seconds field
```

Comment: I have tried to do this, but when I get the following errors super_list = [seconds, self.flowdata, key]

        print super_list.sort(key=lambda row: row[0])

 

‘int’ object not iterable or

‘int’ object unsubsrictpable or the program does run and I get

'None' repeated over and over.

Comment: @user1532369: 1. `super_list` should be a list of lists, but you have only one list representing a single row. Sorting a single row doesn't make sense. 2. `super_list.sort()` does not return a value, it just rearranges the list. If you want to get a sorted list without changing the original, use `sorted(super_list)` instead.

Comment: as it is I have this structure "[[1509321600],    ['1', '-1', '4', '7', '7', '1', '-8', '-14', '-24', '-29', '-25', '-24', '-9', '-4', '0', '0', '-5', '-10', '-6', '-5',  '-13'],    '1441-4731-1-10/30/2017'] " repeated many times.  Do you know how I could change itto this format [[seconds1, flowdata1, key1], [seconds2, flowdata2, key2], ...]:as stated above so I can sort it ?

Comment: sorry I mean this structure "[1509321600, ['1', '-1', '4', '7', '7', '1', '-8', '-14', '-24', '-29', '-25', '-24', '-9', '-4', '0', '0', '-5', '-10', '-6', '-5', '-13'], '1441-4731-1-10/30/2017'] "

Comment: @user1532369: That should work, depending on what you mean by "repeated many times". It should look like `[[12345, ['1','2','3'], 'abc-def-ghi'], [23456, ['4','5','6'], 'qwe-rty-uio']]` for two items.

Answer (score 0):

You could zip the lists into a tuple and then sort the list of tuples, then unpack the tuples with a list comprehension, like so:

```
super_list = [seconds, flowdata, key for zipped_tuple in sorted(zip(super_list[0], super_list[1], super_list[2]))]
```

where seconds, flowdata, key, and zipped_tuple are arbitrary names with no scope beyond the list comprehension.